# Joomla manual login with controller

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, joomla, joomla1.5

I am developing a component for Joomla. It has integrations with popular social websites. I retrieve user information from database via given social profile. Then, I try to make this user login with the following code:

```
$fbuser = $facebook->api(
                '/me',
                'GET',
                array(
                    'access_token' => $_SESSION['active']['access_token']
                )
            );

            // Get a database object
            $db =& JFactory::getDBO();
            $query = "SELECT * FROM #__users WHERE email = '".$fbuser['email']."';";
            $db->setQuery($query);
            $row = $db->loadRow();

            if(isset($row))
            {
                $app = JFactory::getApplication();
                $user =& JUser::getInstance($row[0]);

                $credentials = array();
                $credentials['username'] = $user->get('username');
                $credentials['password'] = $user->get('password'); // When I change this to related users plain password then it works

            $options = array();
                $options['remember']     = true;
                $options['silent']     = true;

                $app->login($credentials, $options);
            }
            else
            {
                return 'There is no account associated with facebook';
            }
```

The problem is database return encoded password and this doesn't work. When I give decoded password to $credentials it works. What can be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to create your own authentication plugin (quite simple task) that would log in any user with a specific password known only to you and the site.

Then you can supply that password along with known username.

For the sake of security, only allow that plugin to log in ordinary users, and not admins.

Answer (score 0):

You need to MD5 hash the pwd (the way it's stored in the DB).

try this:

```
$salt = '19IQYkelXrqVH1Eht6PFOIZRe5T1SQHs';
$pwd = md5_hex($pwd .  $salt) .":$salt";
$query = "select name,username,email,password from jos_users where password = $pwd;";
...
```

Comment: No I already get encoded password with $credentials['password'] = $user->get("password"); and this doesn't work. When I supply plain (not decoded) password it works.

Comment: attach your code and state what is the exact problem/error/failure, then we can review it together and discuss

Comment: Since you don't have the un-hashed password (for security reasons) the only way to login using Facebook is using Facebook API. You can implement it yourself:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/
I made an example you can use, you can download it from here:
http://50.57.82.107/facebook.zip
The file that you'll want to play with is fbTest.php - make sure to update your APP-ID there, and then call this page.

You can also use an existing plugin such as:
http://www.sourcecoast.com/jfbconnect/features/joomla-facebook-login-button

Hope we nailed it this time
;)

Answer (score 0):

```
            // --- login mamanam.com
            $app = JFactory::getApplication();      
            $credentials = array();
            $credentials['username'] = $username;
            $credentials['password'] = $password;
            $app->login($credentials);
```

Necessary parameters in array $credentials=array() for logon function Joomla! $app->login($credentials)

*Sorry my English is not so good

Comment: This answer has been flagged as low quality. If it answers the question, consider adding a bit of text to explain how it works.

Comment: Necessary parameters in array `$credentials=array()` for logon function Joomla! `$app->login($credentials)` ----- Sorry my English is not so good

Comment: Thanks for adding this information. It is better to put it inside of your answer because comments are harder to read and tend to disappear over time.